# How do I connect digital logic components (eg. AND gate) to parts in a circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

This is meant to be part of a systems project I am required to complete. I want to create an alarm system using logic gates. For now, it basically involves:

INPUT: Lever, multiple detectors

This runs into an AND gate (consisting of digital NAND gate components) which then connects to:

OUTPUT: Alarm

How do I connect the NAND gates to each other and also to the lever and the alarm as a permanent circuit? I considered using breadboards, but they're only for temporary use. I heard a permanent solution may be through PCB, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Also any other options?

As you can probably tell, I am a newbie to this, so simple and concise explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Uh for a normal alarm, don't you want at least one of the triggers to turn on? There exists a 8 input OR gate for that. And then just one AND gate to enable and disable the sensors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use perfboard.

> (Perfboard) is a thin, rigid sheet with holes pre-drilled at standard intervals across a grid, usually a square grid of 2.54 mm (0.1 in) spacing. These holes are ringed by round or square copper pads

You can solder all your breadboard compatible components to that. You might need something to mount the lever to, though, depending on it's form factor

As for how to turn NAND gates into AND gates, you just need to invert the output of the NAND gate. You can create an inverter by tying both inputs of a second NAND gate together. Then you simply feed the output of the first gate to the input of the second.

Comment: I looked this up and it seems that perfboard shares a similarity with the breadboard in that it is temporary.

Comment: It can be temporary, but you would need to desolder the components. On the other hand, it's far more permanent than a breadboard and doesn't require designing and etching a custom pcb.